# jmeter all other threads are stuck when it is not getting response for one Thread

Tags: performance, web, jmeter, load-testing

I am new to jmeter.
I am doing load testing on web application using recording feature in jmeter.
The issue is, If I'm giving say 100 with 100s ramp up time in Thread pool for 50 continuous web requests(sequence of web application flow).
If the server is not responding at 25th request(total 50) of 45th Thread(total 100) it is stuck at that point and not sending requests for remaining 55 threads.
What should I do.? is there any other method to initiate the threads.

Answer (score 0):

it is not sending the threads because of many reasons 
1. jmeter memory print you need to check
2. the server you are targeting will accept only no of threads.

etc are there.

if each thread processing time will take x amount of time hence n threads with x amount of time the processor is busy .

if your targeting server can only process 40  in this case i am assuming capacity as 40 , then the 41st request will only get chance , only at least one of the  previous request get processed or released the thread .

too many threads might cause STUCK or BLOCKED threads at the server end in that case we either dont see response or error code . try stopping the threads you see all the reaming as failed requests

Comment: click red X button to get stopped.

Comment: In the thread group section Action to be taken when a sampler result to failure  check stop thread

Answer (score 0):

JMeter shouldn't normally act like you described. Check out *jmeter.log* file, it usually should have enough information to get to the bottom of problem.

It looks like you're trying to run the load test using JMeter GUI. If it's the case - please don't, JMeter is not designed for producing high load in GUI mode.

1. [Run your test in command-line mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. [Delete or disable Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) if any
3. Increase [JVM Heap size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html), JMeter comes with very little value by default.
4. Follow other recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article